# I Can't link to an external css file

Tags: css

Hi I'm new to learning html and css and been really struggling with this problem. I can't link to an eternal CSS file, it just won't work when testing on my web host, I'm sure the file name is right though and it the css works fine when hosting locally. It's saved as "test.css" and is in the same folder as the "index.html" file.

This is my HTML -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
  </head>   
<body>          
  <p>This is some text</p>      
</body>
</html>
```

This is my CSS

```
<style type="text/css"> 
  p {background-color: blue;}
</style>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Uh...are you using a `<style>` tag in a CSS file? You probably don't want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

## Two things...

### 1) remove `</style>` from your header

```
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">

</head>
```

### 2) And remove `<style>` tags from css file

```
p {
  background-color: blue; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to include `<style type="text/css">` in your css file. Remove that and just put:

```
p {
  background-color: blue; 
}
```

The only time you put `<style type="text/css">` is when you're putting the your css directly in your HTML file.

Comment: Thanks for the damn quick responses guys. Removed the style tags and now working fine. Cheers again!

Comment: @MrMrJJ Great! Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS there is no need to wrap your code in a `<style>` tag, that is only necessary in HTML.

Also not sure why there is a closing `</style>` tag below your `<link>` tag. There is currently no inline styling here in the head of your document.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">

    </style>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
```

Comment: True, however this does not answer the question

Comment: @j08691 yes you are right. I've updated my answer to solve his actual problem.